# CentOS 8 - How can I set a client to use a dns server for all domains and one dns for a particular domain?

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, centos8

I'm currently struggle to configure Linux (CentOS 8) in a special way.
The goal should be that my client asks ALWAYS a public DNS Server for everything that is not "example.local". "example.local" should be resolved by an internal DNS.

How can I do that without using a "Fallback" DNS ???

Comment: Usually you provide the internal DNS and configure the internal DNS server to ask the public DNS server for every Domain it doesn't handle itself.

Comment: That's what I thought too....a customer uses his own root DNS without any forwarding.